# Linq, Group By, Join, Average и Count()

Tags: c#, база-данных, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

Имеется вот такая схема БД для написания запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
          var statistic = (from st in context.students
                           join sM in context.setMarks on st.studentId equals sM.studentId
                           join mark in context.marks on sM.markId equals mark.markId
                           join gr in context.groups on st.studentGroup equals gr.groupId
                           where gr.groupName == "8к2492"
                           orderby st.studentSurname
                           select new
                           {
                               st, sM, mark, gr,
                               name = string.Join(" ", st.studentSurname, st.studentName.Substring(0, 1) + "."),
                               marks = string.Join(", ",mark.mark)

                           }).AsEnumerable().GroupBy(stats => stats.st.studentId);
```

```
 public class setMark
    {
        [Key]
        public int setmarkId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Занятие")]
        [Required]
        public int lessonId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Студент")]
        [Required]
        public int studentId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Оценка")]
        public int markId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("studentId")]
        public Student student { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("markId")]
        public Mark mark { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("lessonId")]
        public Lesson lesson { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public class Mark
    {
        [Key]
        public int markId { get; set; }

        [Display (Name ="Оценка")]
        [StringLength(5)]
        [Required]
        public string mark { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int studentId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Фамилия")]
        [StringLength(15)]
        [Required]
        public string studentSurname { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Имя")]
        [StringLength(15)]
        [Required]
        public string studentName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Отчество")]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string studentLastname { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Аватарка")]
        public byte[] studentPic { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Группа")]
        [Required]
        public int studentGroup { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Подгруппа")]
        [Required]
        public int studentSubgroup { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Эмодзи-статус")]
        public int? studentStatus { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string studentUser { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("studentGroup")]
        public collegeGroup group { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("studentSubgroup")]
        public Subgroup subgroup { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("studentUser")]
        public IdentityUser user { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("studentStatus")]
        public EmojiStatus status { get; set; }
    }
```

Суть в том, что необходимо получить ФИО ученика - средний балл ученика - количество оценок ученика, как составить данный запрос?

Comment: в вашем тексте отсутсвует вопрос

Comment: изменил, вопрос добавлен

Comment: У вас у моделей нет внешних ключей в классах? Типа `context.Students. Select(s=>s.Marks…)`?

Comment: В моделях есть внешние ключи, типа [Foreign key(markId)]  Mark mark (на примере setMarks)

Comment: Можете классы моделей показать? Просто есть ощущение, что вам все эти джойны в коде не нужны

Comment: Прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: @Alex текстом добавьте

Comment: у вас у студента нет связи в оценки, что то типа списка оценок в класса Student